# setting an immutable bitmap image gives errors?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-camera, android-canvas

i'm learning about graphics.Camera. and i have taken a picture by the camera and when i set

the taken picture "bitmap image" as canvas, the App crashs and the logcat says "the bitmap

image is immutable". actually, i dont know what does that mean? Any suggestion?

thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
OnClickListener btn01Listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent CameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(CameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);           
    }
};
```

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           ImageView img01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img01);
           //img01.setImageBitmap(image);

           c = new Camera();
           can = new Canvas();
           can.setBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(image));
        }
}
```

LogCaat:

```
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.androidbook.Camera3DDemo/com.androidbook.Camera3DDemo.Camera3DDemoActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.androidbook.Camera3DDemo/com.androidbook.Camera3DDemo.Camera3DDemoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.androidbook.Camera3DDemo/com.androidbook.Camera3DDemo.Camera3DDemoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2107)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  ... 13 more
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.graphics.Canvas.setBitmap(Canvas.java:144)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.androidbook.Camera3DDemo.Camera3DDemoActivity.onActivityResult(Camera3DDemoActivity.java:43)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
03-23 20:46:16.188: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  ... 14 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that means that you don't have the permissions to change the Bitmap. So you will have to create a mutable copy of your provided bitmap which can be used to paint on a Canvas and such.

You can do that by using this method:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(yourBitmap);
```

Comment: i changed the onActivityResult() method, but still the app crashs

Comment: please the check the logcat, posted above

Comment: `Bitmap.createBitmap(yourBitmap);` returns immutable bitmap, while `canvas.setbitmap()` requires mutable one.

Comment: Then you could choose this one: copy(Bitmap.Config config, boolean isMutable) and set isMutable to true

Comment: now, the App works normally, but,  `can.setBitmap(image.copy(Config.ALPHA_8, true));` does not set any image on the screen. Please note that, I'm using the emulator not a real device

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a copy Bitmap with mutable set to true:

```
Bitmap newBMP=image.copy( Bitmap.Congif.ARGB_8888, true );
```

Then you will load the newBMP to canvas.